# How to build an "Evolving" docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker container containing an batch-process doing some computation and storing results in `/data` inside the container. Whenever the application is started it needs to continue computing from the last stored state in `/data`

For reasons I cannot make `/data` some kind of volume or external storage, but it needs to be inside the container.

To not have to do computations several times, I try to create a new image based on the actual state of `/data` after each run of my batch.

`/data` is quite big and contains a lot of files, however the changes on that directory after one batch execution are small. So I want to achive a layer stack like this:

```
Update run +...                                     (some MB)
Update run +2                                       (some MB)
Update run +1                                       (some MB)
First update run                                    (some MB)
Initial run                                         (several GB)
Base layer containing application and empty `/data` (some 100 MB for initial stack)
```

The initial run layer would be quite large since it contains all the results from the beginning. Update runs just contain a small set of changed data inside `/data`

I tried the following:

- start base container (empty `/data`)
- commit state after batch run to some temporary image
- do a multistage build looking like this

```
FROM temporary_image as actual_state
FROM prepared_batch

COPY --from=actual_state /data /data
```

- start the next iteration based on `prepared_batch`
- commit state after batch run to some temporary image
- do that multistage build again
- ...

As resulting layer stack I get the following

```
Update run +...                                     (several GB)
Update run +2                                       (several GB)
Update run +1                                       (several GB)
First update run                                    (several GB)
Initial run                                         (several GB)
Base layer containing application and empty `/data` (some 100 MB for initial stack)
```

So it seems my understanding of how layer normalization works was not right. What is the right approach to achieve my target layer structure? Is it possible at all?

Comment: May I ask what restrictions you face, so that you cannot use volumes/external storage?

Comment: The application I'm talking about is the first stage in a process. The second stage has more workload and gets parallelized. So after the new image has been created it gets multiple time instantiated by the second stage. That stages have also write access to `/data`, so can't use readonly volumes. 
So yes, adapting the second stage to write their somewhere else, and using a rm volume in first stage and ro in second stage might be a solution, too.